# Apache POI getStringCellValue() printing null

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm getting a weird error while trying to read the Cell values through Apache POI in java:

```
 System.out.println(row.getCell(13, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue())
```

is always printing `null`, even after specifying the Missing policy as `Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK`.My writing logic to the Cell is :

```
public void writeCell( String value, Sheet sheet, int rowNum, int colNum)
{
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
    }
    Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    if (value == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    cell.setCellValue(value);
}
```

When I'm writing to Cell at colNum = 13 , the String value object is null. I'm not able to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't do what you seem to think it does:

```
System.out.println(row.getCell(13, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue())
```

In effect, that's doing

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(13);
if (cell == null) { cell = row.createCell(13, Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK); }
```

So, if there is nothing in that cell, it creates it as an empty blank one

Then, you try doing:

```
 cell.getStringCellValue()
```

This only works for `String` cells, and in the missing case you've told POI to give you a `Blank` new cell!

If you really just want a string value of a cell, use [DataFormatter.formatCellValue(Cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) - that returns a String representation of your cell including formatting. Otherwise, check the type of your cell before trying to fetch the value!

Answer (score 0):

The [getStringCellValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getStringCellValue%28%29) on the `Cell` interface would return `""` if your code worked as supposed (setting the call blank).
Is it not possible that value for col id 13 is not `null` but `"null"`?

Comment: No that is not possible as I'm not setting value to be "null" anywhere. It is null object.